# How can I store a column info into a List of String from an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I am using VB and I want to commpare two lists of Strings.

One comes from a folder: file names (no problem whith that)

And the other comes from a query:

```
Select name from fileTable where status = "active"
```

I need to store "name" which is a String then compare both list and do some other things. It woukd be something like this:

List 1 (files from folder names)

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
image4.jpg
```

List2 (fales names form query which are active)

```
image1.jpg
image3.jpg
```

Ive been reading lots of examples, but I cannot store "name" column in my list

What I have tried:

```
Public Function ActivosSQL() As List(Of String)

    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    Dim conStr = "My connection"
    Dim sql As String = "Select name from fileTable where status = 'active'"
    Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection(conStr)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

    sqlConnection1.Open()

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        list.Add(reader.GetString("name"))
    End While

 return list
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know what error you are getting, but as a guess, [`SqlDataReader.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not take a string with the column name as the parameter - it takes the ordinal of the column.  So, you want something like:

```
list.Add(reader.GetString(0))
```

You could also look up the column ordinal with `GetOrdinal` (probably best to do the `GetOrdinal` call outside of the loop):

```
list.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name")))
```

Comment: ooooh Yeah I am getting an error which say that cannot convert to an Integer indeed. I'll check whit this :D thank you so much!

Comment: THANK YOU!! I made some tests and it works wonderfuly :D now I can continue.